# tightvncserver - show the same screen on hdmi and vncclient

Tags: vnc

Can I start tightvncserver to show the same screen on hdmi screen and vncclient?

I tried -alwaysshared, but could see no difference.

**Edit**
I want to remotely control Pi, using keyboard, mouse on remote (Mac), and have display on Pi hdmi screen as well as remote. I used to do this in the distant past, running Linux from a Windows PC. Further research indicates tightvncserver can't do this (so what does -alwaysshared do?). I also tried x11vnc, but can't get this to do anything on the Mac.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your question?  Right now it is somewhat vague and hard to answer.

Comment: You should edit that into the question just in case some person doesn't read that comment.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should install x11vnc and configure it to get same screen on HDMI and also vnc client.

```
apt-get install x11vnc
```

then run x11vnc command with parameters.

```
x11vnc -display :0 -usepw -listen IP_of_pi -allow allowed_ip_address

-display : screen number to get
-usepw   : use password security
-listen  : IP address of server (Pi IP)
-allow   : allowed client IPs (client IP, in your case Mac IP address)
```

Then use a VNC client on your Mac, i prefer 'Chicken of VNC' and connect to Pi IP address.

**Update:**
To tune VNC connection for performance you can use those parameters.

-noxdamage -ncache 10 -ncache_cr

You can find more parameters and definitions of x11vnc at http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html

Good information about x11vnc :
http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/

Comment: Thanks, I got this going. I still have to do a bit more to fine tune it for my use; My hdmi monitor is larger than the Macbook. I have not used Chicken of VNC since OS X 10.4, but OS X Screen Sharing does not work with x11vnc, although I use this with tightvncserver.

Comment: I'm using trial version of JollyFastVNC too.

Comment: I'm still seeing black (with X cursor). I'm running this via bash w `-create`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, helped me a lot. In this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=108862#p108862 a guy proposes the same solution and also shows how to enable that on boot.

Comment: For Mac you can use the built-in VNC client: Open Finder > Go > Connect To Server > type e.g. `vnc://192.168.1.123:5901` and click _Connect_.

Comment: Finally an option that works... I had errors while installing with a file missing end of file character and not being able to log int using my newly created user... it was likely a power related SD card corruption...

Answer (score -2):

you should look into synergy tho i just found out that it went paid but you can find an older version here http://synergy.soft32.com/ or you can get the source and compile it free also its an open source app but went paid because lack of donation

Comment: It is a bit hard to compile, I almost would vote this down because you pay for Synergy then you find you can't get Raspberry Pi to work with it unless you compile as @Jesterod said - However if you have to go through all that then, also as he said, you don't need to pay.. I find that kind of deceptive at best to say it's a "solution" for Pi without MUCH MORE disclosure about the problems that go with it.