# Remote Connection to Pi to same Display as HDMI Port

Tags: hdmi, display, remote

Is there a way I can remotley connect to the Raspberry Pi and get the same Screen as it is shown on the HDMI Connection?

We need the Pi for a Screen in the entrance Hall of our Building, and i can get a remote Connection working, but it will always make me a virtual Display and the Display connected via HDMI Port does not Show the same Thing.

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,basically there is an option to get shared display in VNC, see documentation for ":0 configuration", but getting this up is more difficult than :1 or more with no sharing.
search google for "tightvnc 5900 linux"
There is a link: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sharing-desktop-with-tightvnc-314667/
(Not tested)
Next link from THIS site: [tightvncserver - show the same screen on hdmi and vncclient](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/tightvncserver-show-the-same-screen-on-hdmi-and-vncclient)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

The first time you run the server it will prompt you to set a password. This is the password that you use when connecting remotely.

```
/usr/bin/tightvncserver
```

There is no need to create a view only password, unless you have a specific need.

Then install and start on the linux box, from which you're going to connect.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

OR (if it doesnt work)

```
sudo apt-get install ssvnc
```

Run it on the pi:

```
/usr/bin/tightvncserver
```

Run on the machine you want to view from

```
xtightvncviewer <ip of the Rpi >:1
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use [`barrier`](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) to control your RPi's local HDMI desktop with a remote keyboard and mouse, and then forward that local desktop either to a local second display (connected to the RPi) using

```
xrandr --output <secondary_display> --same-as <primary_display>
```

or as a video stream (using [`ffmpeg -f x11grab`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489498/106927)) to a remote display or even a video player / web browser window.

This is especially useful if the HDMI screen is visible when you want to control it, as you can forego the second step (video forwarding) altogether, which mean a much lower network load and graphical interface responsiveness comparable to a local desktop.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is the free version of TeamViewer https://www.teamviewer.com

Comment: There is a Raspberry Pi install instruction here: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-teamviewer/