# SSH connection and filling out a field in a browser

Tags: ssh, remote

With a SSH connection I can open midori:

```
pi@raspberry$ DISPLAY=:0 midori http://www.google.com
```

Google loads up as normal

**Q:** How can I, from the terminal search for something whilst Google is loaded? And then enter 3rd result found? Also I would like to remotely enter (for example) my email, and enter my password and email address when I open gmail.com remotely?

How can I remotely enter these things (what I want to search, my email address, my password, etc)?

Comment: How about using remote desktop ? :)

Comment: Yeah, i would use vnc for sure if you are trying to get to a more desktop/laptop feel.

Comment: @dastaan Didn't think of Remote Desktop - but [here](http://www.raspberrypiblog.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-from.html) is an excellent reference for anyone else who would be keen on a Remote Desktop appraoch

Comment: @dastaan I would ideally like to mirror the raspberry pi onto my laptop - but what I can achieve currently is just tap into raspberry with [xrdp](http://www.raspberrypiblog.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-from.html) and do stuff on the RPi with my laptop -but- the stuff I do doesn't get mirrored onto the screen the raspberry is connected to.  How can I mirror what I do on my laptop to the screen the RPi is hooked up to? (Raspberry pi is hooked to 40" TV via HDMI)

Comment: Oh you can mirror the screen as well. Here is the link. :) http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/tightvncserver-show-the-same-screen-on-hdmi-and-vncclient

Comment: Another approach (in case of remote desktop is not possible at all) could be using automizing tools such as `xdotool` or something similar. (There're couple of libraries for doing so in python). You can generate keyboard strokes and mouse clicks by command and other facilities such as focusing a window and lot more. One can have a look at this documentation : http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml  more info. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If a GUI is out of the question (since your question states "from the terminal"), have a look at [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

However google isn't super friendly to curl.

So you might want to have a look [here](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-use-google-search-from-the-terminal/) to have a more readable result.

Answer (score 1):

Try using xdg-open.  This will open the site in the currently registered application for URIs on the remote linux system.  If the browser is not already open, it will start it. If the application is already running, it will open a new tab (if the application allows it).  Since you are using the remote display in the OP (`export DISPLAY=:0`) this will cause page to open there (again, as long as midori is your default browser - which you can check with `xdg-settings --list`).

Example:

`xdg-open http://www.google.com`

For more info on xdg-open, look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open).

If, on the other hand, you are really wanting a remote-control style solution, *without* the extra weight of an RDP or TeamViewer style options, consider using something that allows a local XWin server (such as Cygwin does for Windows hosts, or already available in any linux system) for your SSH connection.  Then all you will need to do is connect with `-X` in your ssh command and the application gui will arrive on your local system, but be *running* on the remote.  In this way you will not need all the extra desktop stuff.