# Is there a software to see on my PC that mirrors exactly what I am doing on the Raspberry Pi touchscreen?

Tags: touchscreen, vnc

I have the Raspberry Pi Official Touch Display and would like to mirror in a PC what a see on the Raspberry Pi's screen, is this clear? Is there a software that will allow me to see, on my PC, the exact image of what I'm doing on the Raspberry Pi? This is for presentation purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The VNC software package will do exactly that .... have a look at:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

For a full recipe.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer may help https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9610/8697 You will probably need to install `X11` software on Windows.

Just running VNC will not show the same screen, but will start a new session.